# how to pass a variable into a method call like @photo_main.file.url(:img_120x120)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, variables, methods, carrierwave

Using Carrierwave to upload Images, 
I want to write 1 function to handle all my image includes in several sizes.

```
  image_tag @photo_main.file.url(:img_122x145) rescue nil
```

The :img_120x120 is defined in Carrierwave uploader but why the :img_120x120 semicolon before its name? In what format is this?

Wanted outcome:

```
def get_avatar(size)

   image_tag @photo_main.file.url(size) rescue nil

end
```

How could this be done?

**UPDATE 1:**

Fails with : ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `file' for nil:NilClass):
    1: .ruler
    2: 
    3: //= show_avatar_profile(@profile.id)
    4: = show_avatar_new(@profile.id, "96x96")

```
  def show_avatar_new(id, size)

    puts "size is"
    size =  size.to_sym
    puts size

    @photo_main = Photo.where(:attachable_id => id, :attachable_type => "Profile", :main => true, :moderated => true, :approved => true).first
    @photo = Photo.where(:attachable_id => id, :attachable_type => "Profile", :moderated => true, :approved => true).first

    if @photo_main
      image_tag @photo_main.file.url(size)
    else
      image_tag @photo.file.url(size)
    end

  end
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^[:word:]\.\-\+]/

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end


  version :img_48x48 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [48, 48]
  end

  version :img_58x58 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [58, 58]
  end

  version :img_75x75 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [75, 75]
  end

  version :img_96x96 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [96, 96]
  end

  # Used in search results,
  version :img_122x145 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [122, 145]
  end

  version :img_200x200 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
  end


  protected

  def secure_token(length=32)
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.hex(length/2))
  end

  def delete_empty_upstream_dirs
    path = ::File.expand_path(store_dir, root)
    Dir.delete(path) # fails if path not empty dir

    path = ::File.expand_path(base_store_dir, root)
    Dir.delete(path) # fails if path not empty dir
  rescue SystemCallError
    true # nothing, the dir is not empty
  end

end
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `url(size)` is the correct way to get a specific version of an image in CarrierWave, can you also post your uploader code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, things beginning with colons `:` (not semicolons `;`!) are symbols, which are essentially immutable strings.

```
"img_122x145".to_sym # => :img_122x145
```

It seems like what you've written there is exactly what you need. If you're wondering where to put it, you could put it in a helper

```
# app/helpers/avatar_helper.rb
def get_avatar(size)
  image_tag @photo_main.file.url(size)
end
```

Please don't use `rescue nil` there, though. What error are you trying to catch? It would be much better to explicitly avoid it rather than using exceptions as flow control.

```
image_tag @photo_main.file.url(size) if @photo_main.file?
```

would be sufficient to avoid the problem of a `@photo_main` without a `file`, and is much more intention-revealing (and, in fact, more performant). Worst-case, you should still explicitly state what sort of error you're expecting to get

```
def get_avatar(size)
  image_tag @photo_main.file.url(size)
rescue SomeSpecificErrorThatCantBeAvoided
  nil
end
```

[This short (<3min) screencast](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/11/19/rubytapas-022-inline-rescue/) makes an excellent case for avoiding inline rescue.

---

**Update**

When you create versions in CarrierWave, it creates methods to access them - you don't pass an argument to `url`:

```
@photo.file.img_122x145.url
```

If you want to get a variable version, though, they are available through `versions` (a hash):

```
size = :img_122x145
@photo.file.versions[size].url
```

That won't solve your remaining problem, which is simply that your queries aren't finding anything.

Comment: thank you for the great writeup and clarification. The rescues are very bad indeed, its an old method I wrote like 1 year ago when ive started with rails. Im trying to make carrierwave display the default image which fails also. I refactor and post back thanks a lot

Comment: Tried your suggestion by converting the variable to a .to_sym but that does not seem to fix, it still fails do you have any idea what im missing?

Comment: You shouldn't need a `to_sym` if you pass the argument as a symbol like `get_avatar(:img_122x145)`. The error message is telling you that you are trying to call `file` on `nil`, which means that your `@photo_main` and `@photo` must both be `nil`.